# How to set max date on jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, I need to transform it into a datepicker with max date today:

```
    $('.ptum-editor-date').datepicker(datapicker_regional).on('changeDate', function (e) {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
    })
```

I have this configuration for the datapicker_regional variable:

```
var datapicker_regional = {
    autoclose: false,
    beforeShowDay: $.noop,
    calendarWeeks: false,
    clearBtn: false,
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [],
    forceParse: true,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    keyboardNavigation: true,
    language: 'es',
    minViewMode: 0,
    multidate: false,
    multidateSeparator: ',',
    orientation: "auto",
    rtl: false,
    startDate: -Infinity,
    endDate: Infinity,
    startView: 0,
    todayBtn: false,
    todayHighlight: true,
    weekStart: 1

};
```

If I put maxdate:0 won't work.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I visited their website just now

```
<input type="text" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-end-date="0d">
```

According to Bootstrap Datepicker

> Date. Default: End of time
>
> The latest date that may be selected; all later dates will be disabled.

The above code `Will disable all dates after today.`

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options.html#id6

Answer (score 0):

https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate

```
$('#datetimepicker').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(new Date())
```

Or

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
   maxDate : 'now'
});
```

Comment: This looks like it's for datetimepicker. It seems like OP was looking for datepicker

Comment: the second answer didn't work and about the first one I'm using datepicker in a jquery part.